# AngularJS 4 - Communicate between components getting data from routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I've this UI:
[image]

And this is my code structure:

[image]

My app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { AboutComponent } from './about';
import { NoContentComponent } from './no-content';

import { DataResolver } from './app.resolver';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Home' } },
  { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

And my sidenav.component.html has a pageTitle variable on the template, as follow:

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">

        <menu-list #menuList></menu-list>

    </md-sidenav>

    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </button>

        <div>{{ pageTitle }}</div>

    </md-toolbar>

    <main class="app-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

What I want to do is:

- Grab the title from route each time a new route is fired
- Place the title on the `pageTitle` `sidenav.component.ts` variable

Should I use a Service Events to communicate between components?
What's the best and easy way to get title each time a route is fired?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Marcelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you subscribe to Router.events

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
...
constructor(
    private _router: Router ,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this._activatedRoute)
      .map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      })
      .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      .subscribe((event) => this.pageTitle = event['title']);
}
```

Comment: Hi. What about life cycle of the app? On my sidenav component, ngOnInit() will run only once.
I can subscribe to Router.events on app.component, but here I won't be access to `this.pageTitle` since it's on another component.

Comment: You can subscribe to Router.events in your sidenav component too

Comment: Thanks. How stupid I was because I thought I couldn't user router evens on other components :/